# Extend ImageView with Rhombus Shape

Tags: android, imageview

Hello does anyone knows how to make a ImageView Object with this shape? 
                                                 http://smorenburg.me/shape.png

```
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
          Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
          if (drawable == null) {
                 return;
          }
          if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
                 return;
          }
          Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
          Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
          int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
          Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
          canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
   }
```

Comment: see `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable` sources and see how they did a rounded rectangle, do the same with rounded and rotated square

Comment: Yes that is currently the one Im using but I don't get how I can manage to make a Rhombus Shape, thank you!

Comment: So how did they managed a rounded rect?

Comment: getting the code from somewhere in Google, but I cant find or make it with Rhombus shape.